# How to differentiate between Volume and File handle in winapi?

Tags: c, windows, file, winapi, volume

I am iterating over all the handles opened by my process after making sure that I have opened up a volume handle. During iteration, I use GetFinalPathNameByHandle() to receive information about object associated with the certain handle but as I see it this function only works with files and returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (0x06) error in case of handles other than files. Am I right on this? If yes, then how can I check whether the handle in question is associated with volume so that I can close it?

Any help woudl be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? If you have opened a volume handle, you already know that it is a volume handle, right? No need to iterate, really. Relying on `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` is a bad solution, as it will not only identify a volume handle, but any kind of invalid handle (e.g. window handles or handles that are invalid alltogether). You cannot really close handle that's presumably invalid either, if it's invalid, what would you expect closing it to do?

Comment: Also, opening a volume handle isn't something that happens by accident or unnoticed. It's an operation that requires privilegue elevation. So if you are worried about "accidentially" getting to a volume handle, then don't fear -- this is not going to happen.

Comment: The problem is that I haven't opened the volume handle by my self. It is being opened by Qfilesystemwatcher object in QT from which I am creating GUI for my program and before calling my code (which requires volume to be locked), I need to close this handle opened by file system watcher.

Comment: Why do you not destroy the Qfilesystemwatcher then while you're locking the volume (and presumably doing something low-level on the drive)? It's not going to function properly anyway if you try to force-close the handle using some hack. So you could as well destroy the object and let it clean up by itself (closing the handle). When you need to watch the filesystem again. create a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this all wrong. When you create a handle, remember it. When you are done with it, close it.

You cannot hope to be able to enumerate all open handles in your process and close a bunch of them that meet some criteria. You have no way of knowing whether or not the handle is in use. There will be handles open in your process that were not opened by your code. Closing such handles will lead to all sorts of pain.

Comment: But how does "process explorer" kind of programs forcefully close handles of other programs? Does that mean we can not close handles used by our process which are opened by some third party code but we can force closure of handles opened by other processes? I would love to have knowledge about all this.

Comment: Forcibly closing handles is certainly not normal. You are expected to look after your handles and close them when you are done.

Comment: I've just read the comments to the question. Forcibly closing handles opened by other objects will lead to pain. That's the scenario in the second part of my answer. Don't pursue this approach. Do it properly.